# Include requirements in PHP with NGINX

Tags: php, nginx, path, include

I have a code in PHP, which includes some files using absolute files like:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/frontend/src" . "/requests/Requests.inc");
```

Locally it launches successfully. But when I try to launch it in my NGINX docker container it writes that file isn't found.

**NGINX root path:** /var/www/html/

**Index.php is in:** /frontend/src

I tried to determine for my paths, NGINX root as zero point, and changed it too

```
require_once("/frontend/src" . "/requests/Requests.inc");
```

Still it doesn't work. Since that moment I don't understand, how does absolute path in NGINX + PHP work?

Comment: If you log into your container and do `ls /frontend/src/requests`, do you see Requests.inc, or do you get an error?

Comment: Given Index.php is in: /frontend/src, it must be the DOCUMENT_ROOT already. Either way, why don't you just echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] and see what does it contain?

Comment: Besides, the error message contains all the information you need - the full path to your script and the full path which is trying to be included. All you need is compare the two

Comment: I tried to print in via echo. 

In the frist option it returned full path starts from /var/... and it was a real file path in docker. But PHP returned me an exception that this file doesn't exist. 

In the second option it printed that path: /frontend/src/requests - of cause in docker there is no files, but i thought it counts in NGINX environment